# Problem with reference system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I've imported into QGIS two vector detasets and set the correct reference system. First is a shapefile, second is a csv file. The problem is that they are in different places, but they should be one over the other (see image).

How can I solve this?

[image].stack.imgur.com/7dwzJ.png

Comment: Were they both created using the same CRS?

Comment: Don't know, how could I check? Anyway I've enabled on the fly projection so it should automatically set the predefined CRS, am I wrong?

Comment: edit: SOLVED! I had to disable on the fly projection and set the correct reference system for the second vector, that was different from the first.. as you intended I think.. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Awesome! Sorry I didn't get back to you. Luckily you fixed it. Sometimes there's no way to determine the original projection.